Не импортируется база данных в OSP
mysql> SOURCE B:\ospanel\domains\bd\orders.sql
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@DBC_links
INSERT INTO `b_sale_order_props_value` (`ID`, `ORDER_ID`, `ORDER_PROP' at line 1
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'testdb2.b_sale_order_props_value' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'testdb2.b_sale_order_props_value' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'testdb2.b_sale_order_props_value' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@DBC_links' at line 1


Table 'testdb2.b_sale_order_props_value' doesn't exist - вам перевести?

При импорте testdb2.b_sale_order_props_value многократно выдает ошибку ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'testdb2.b_sale_order_props_value' doesn't exist. Я новичок и хз как это пофиксить

Вам пишут, что в базе данных testdb2 таблица b_sale_order_props_value не найдена (ее не существует). Как пофиксить? Создать таблицу, как минимум.
